# Fixed height of div regardless of elements inside

Tags: html, css

For reporting purposes I want a div `report-canvas` with a fixed height in `mm`:

```
.report-canvas {
    height: 335mm;
    min-height: 335mm;
    max-height: 335mm;
}
```

A page has this structure:

```
  <div class="a4">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="report-canvas"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

This works fine when `.report-canvas` doesn't have any child elements. But when I start to add `h2`'s, `table`'s and other `div`'s, then the footer is pushed down outside of the page and the `report-canvas` is too big. How can I force `report-canvas` to always have the same size regardless of child elements?

This is the CSS of the other elements:

```
.a4 {
    page-break-before:always;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    width: 250mm;
    height: 365mm;
  }
.header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 35px;
  }
.footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: An explanation:
**1)** You want to have the possibility to scroll the `report-canvas` content.
**2)** You don't care to show the `report-canvas` children that exceed the height.
**3)** You want to show the children of `report-canvas` over that height in a new `a4`

Comment: @benny-ben Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: scroll` on `report-canvas`